# How should we see the role of deduction systems like NK, NJ, LK, LJ?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

I'm not sure to understand how I should see the role of deductions systems like the Sequent Calculus.

- I've always see them as mere syntactic "tools" to formalize deductions/inferences in a logical system.
- But it is said in the *Blind Spot, Chapter 3.1.1*, (J-Y Girard) that

  > Sequent calculus is due to Gentzen (1934). It is a formulation, among others,
  >   of predicate calculus. [...]
  >
  > Before Gentzen, logic was formulated in "Hilbert-style" formal systems [...]

What does he meant by a "formulation of predicate calculus". Can we see the *Sequent Calculus* as an independant primitive definition of a logic i.e An alternative to the usual presentation of logic ?

So what is the relation between these systems and the usual formalization of logic as we can often see under the form Syntax + Semantic.

Comment: The relation is first of all historical: Frege and Russell& Whitehead into *Principia* and then Hilbert formalized the logical calculus (first the predicate one and then the propositional one) with *axioms* and *rules*. The modern "codification" was due to Hilbert & Ackermann (1928) and thus we usually call this formulation as : "Hilbert-style".

Comment: In the '30s Gentzen formulated the rules-only calculus of Natural Deduction and the related Sequent Calculus.

Comment: Maybe usefule : Francis Pelletier, [A Brief History of Natural Deduction](http://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/NDHistory.pdf) (1999).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Interesting. (1) By "modern codification" you're refering to that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system (Axioms + Modus Ponens) ? As far as I know it isn't that modern. (2) When did the logical language used by most mathematicians now came ? The one presented in every "introduction to logic" books when speaking of First-Order Logic.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA (3) When defining a logic, we have to introduce the syntax THEN we have either a semantic-view of Logic or a syntactic one (Natural Deduction, Sequent Calculus), right ? I'm not sure to understand what deduction systems are an alternative for. Are they an alternative to the semantic view of logic ? To the whole language of FOL as used by most mathematicians now ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Good question. I'm not sure to know how to answer that. In most undergraduate textbooks we learn (maybe a bit naively) that a logic is made of a vocabulary/syntax to make expressions and then we have a semantic associated to these expressions to give them a meaning. What I don't understand exacly is where proof systems are situated within this view of logic : I don't have an accurate representation of formal logic in my mind and textbooks doesn't really help for the intuition behind technical details.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA By the way, why do you answer as comments rather as a "real answer" (in the context of StackExchange) ?

Comment: "Modern" means : end of 19th-beginning of 20th Centuries, compared to the "birth" of formal logic : [Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/), around 350 BCE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with a language: a set of basic symbols and a set of syntactical rules.

Syntax defines the "well formed" expressions of the language: the formulae.

Semantics defines the meaning of the expressions and their truth-value.

[First order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) is defined by the use of quantifiers restricted to individual variables: no quantification of predicate symbols is allowed.

We focus the attention on a subset of the "meaningful" formulae : the [(universally) valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity) ones.

The calculi or [proof systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_calculus) are aimed at deriving **all and only** the valid formulae.

Historically, various "styles" of proof systems has been found : from [Frege](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/frege/) to Russell & Whitehead's [Principia Mathematica](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/principia-mathematica/) and then [Hilbert](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hilbert-program/), the first formalizations of the logical calculus (first the predicate one and then the propositional one) were organized with axioms (many) and rules (typically one or two : *modus ponens* and *generalization*).

The modern "codification" can be found into Hilbert & Ackermann's [Grundzüge der theoretischen Logik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Mathematical_Logic) (1928), and thus we usually call this formulation as : "Hilbert-style".

In the '30s [Gerhard Gentzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerhard_Gentzen) formulated the rules-only calculus of Natural Deduction and the related Sequent Calculus.

All them are alternative formulations of (propositional and first-order) *logic* and they are equivalent in the sense that the respective calculus are all sound and complete for (propositional and first-order) validity.

---

Maybe of interest :

- John Corcoran, [Three Logical Theories](https://philpapers.org/archive/CORTLT.pdf) (1969)
- John Corcoran, [Conceptual Structure of Classical Logic](https://philpapers.org/archive/CORCSO.pdf) (1972)
- Stewart Shapiro, [Varieties of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=A_w_BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT3) (2014).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just read (there : https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~lutz/papers/WhatLogicProof.pdf, bottom of page 2) that the syntax+semantic view was a model-theorist view of Logic while proof system+cut elimination was a proof-theorist one. Then I guess these view are both alternative to the other ? Therefore Proof Systems can substitute the popular presentation of logic : "Logic is syntax+semantic". What do you think about that ?

Comment: @BorisEng - NO, not alternative... The propositional calculus has an algorithm for validity : truth-table. But there is no such method to test for first-order validity: thus, the need of a proof system apt to generate valid formulae: the theorems of the calculus.

Comment: So the propositional calculus doesn't necessarily need a proof system while the predicate calculus do ?

Comment: Thanks for the texts you added.